# how to use the same form to display the data of different tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this form that allows users to display, modify, add informations to small tables.  The idea is to have predefined lists for all the drop down menus in our application.  Those list all have the same structure.  I was looking into a way to reuse the same form.

My goal is to be able to make a call that would look like this :

```
frmDescriptions formBoites = new frmDescriptions("Title of the form", "NameOfTheTable");
```

and the form would load and display the table content.

Hopefully I am clear here...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By adding arguments to the form's constructor, you can give it any values you want. This enables the call you suggested.

```
public frmDescriptions(string title, string tableName) // if you need any other values, add them to this list of arguments
{
    InitializeComponent(); // make sure you don't remove this call!

    this.Text = title;
    // set the table's name here and do any other loading procedures you have to
}
```

Comment: I didn't ask correctly my question.... I was actually wondering how to use the tablename to work with the table.  Add, modify etc...  for the title I had figured it out.  Thanks for helping.  MesDonneesEntities4 mde = new MesDonneesEntities4();
            var listeArr = from ra in mde.Arrondissements select ra; how would I use the table name to replace the mde.Arrondissements  I haven't found any way to use a string there